# How to run a task in fixed intervals in a multiple-instances Tomcat env.?

Tags: java, multithreading, task

I'm scheduling background task to run in fixed-intervals, but as tomcat is running in multiple instances (i.e. multiple start Apache servers; 3 in my case), then the task runs 3 times in each interval.. I would like it to run once (no matter the number of Tomcat instances running).

I'm running a servlet loaded on startup (in web.xml) which will initiate my task:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>OnInit</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>box.OnInit</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

OnInit class initiate single instance of that class:

```java
public class BGTaskRefresh {
    private static BGTaskRefresh refreshTaskFactory = null;
    private final Timer timer = new Timer();

    public BGTaskRefresh() {}
    public static void init()
    {
        if( refreshTaskFactory == null )
        {
            refreshTaskFactory = new BGTaskRefresh();
            refreshTaskFactory.start();
        }
    }

    public void start() 
    {
        timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() 
            {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        boxService box = new boxService();
                        box.refreshMethod();
                    } 
                },                      
                5 * 60 * 1000,   // 5-Min Delay for first run
            60 * 60 * 1000); // 60-Mins (Interval between 2 runs)                   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler), especially its [clustering](https://web.archive.org/web/20190128025544/http://www.quartz-scheduler.org:80/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering) capabilities:

[image: two muppets]
<sub>(source: [quartz-scheduler.org](http://quartz-scheduler.org/images/documentation/2.x/quartz_cluster.png))</sub>

This might be an overkill in your situation, but Quartz will take care of running the job on only a single instance (using database for synchronization) and will automatically run the job on an idle server.

Another option is [hazelcast](/questions/tagged/hazelcast) and distributed locks and queues it provides.

Comment: It seems i (we?) are missing something here. Isn't Java Timer built-in capabilities should be able to handle it? I mean, having fixed-intervals is quite common, and also having your application server run in multiple instances..

Comment: @Haim: how? [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) is just a Java class managing few threads. If you have several JVMs (possibly on different machines), how is that class suppose to know about other instances? They are completely independent - that's why your task is executed on each of them and that's why you have answers mentioning Quartz, database and file locking - because you need some sort of synchronization/coordination outside of the JVM. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of synchronization mechanism. Although ideally you'd want a distributed scheduler (e.g. Quartz cluster), considering your usage scenario you're likely to have either some mechanism for shared session state or a shared database underlying your application; you can simply record the operation and grab a database-based lock to ensure only one instance will run the command at a time (and double-check after the lock grab to ensure you're not running the same task twice).

Here's one article I've found with a technique for DB-based locking: http://blog.udby.com/archives/15